# count occurrences in multiple columns (but for each row) based on value in another column

Tags: r

I am currently trying to analyse a data set in which I have one column that gives me the value of interest for each row (column called value_needed) and then a bunch of columns (in reality around 150) that have values and also a lot of NA's. For each row I would like to count the number of occurrences of that value from column value_needed in all the other columns, here position_1:position_6.

Here is some fake data:

```
position_1 <- c(6, -8, 8, 0, 0, -6)
position_2 <- c(NA, 6, -8, 8, 8, 0)
position_3 <- c(NA, NA, 6, -8, 0, 8)
position_4 <- c(NA, NA, NA, 6, -8, -8)
position_5 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 6, 8)
position_6 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6)

value_needed <- c(0, 6, -8, 8, 0, 8)

df <- data.frame(position_1, position_2, position_3,position_4, position_5, position_6,value_needed)
```

In the ideal case I would need to create a new column (name it occ) that counts the occurrences of the value in column value_needed from all position columns in that particular row.

The output for this fake data set above would be then:

```
occ = c(0,1,1,1,2,1)
```

If anyone has any hints, I really appreciate that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `base` solution

```
df$occ <- rowSums(df[1:6] == df$value_needed, na.rm = T)
```

---

#### `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(occ = sum(c_across(pos_1:pos_6) == value_needed, na.rm = T)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

#### output

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 8
#   pos_1 pos_2 pos_3 pos_4 pos_5 pos_6 value_needed   occ
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
# 1     6    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA            0     0
# 2    -8     6    NA    NA    NA    NA            6     1
# 3     8    -8     6    NA    NA    NA           -8     1
# 4     0     8    -8     6    NA    NA            8     1
# 5     0     8     0    -8     6    NA            0     2
# 6    -6     0     8    -8     8     6            8     2
```